# save png to server using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html2canvas

I am using a method from [this tutorial](http://developergang.com/convert-div-image-using-html2canvas-save-using-ajax-php/) 
to save a picture generated with html to a png or jpeg file in server.

I suspect there is an error in the original script but cannot find it

the picture should appear in the image_id div, but it does not.

here is my code:

```
<body>
<div class='container' id="printableArea">
...here goes the div to output as png
</div>
<div id="image_id">
<img src="" alt="image" />
</div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>


     <script>
     html2canvas([document.getElementById('printableArea')], {

    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var imagedata = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        var imgdata = imagedata.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
        //ajax call to save image inside folder}
        $.ajax({
            url: 'save_image.php',
            data: {
                   imgdata:imgdata
                   },
            type: 'post',
            success: function (response) {   
               console.log(response);
               $('#image_id img').attr('src', response)

        }
    });
    }
    </script>
```

the php file i use is the following:

```
<?php 
$imagedata = base64_decode($_POST['imgdata']);
$filename = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
//path where you want to upload image
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/'.$filename.'.png';
$imageurl  = 'http://***.com/images/'.$filename.'.png';
file_put_contents($file,$imagedata);
echo $imageurl;
?>
```

Comment: Does the image get saved to the correct folder? What shows up in the console.log?

Comment: Nothing saved in folder

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code is missing some end } and ) for ending of onrendered and html2canvas:

```
    <script>
 html2canvas([document.getElementById('printableArea')], {

onrendered: function (canvas) {
    var imagedata = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    var imgdata = imagedata.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'save_image.php',
            data: {
                   imgdata:imgdata
                   },
            type: 'post',
            success: function (response) {   
               console.log(response);
               $('#image_id img').attr('src', response);

        }
    });
}});
</script>
```